# Cannot SSHFS mount user home directory

Tags: mount, ssh, sshfs, fuse

I am attempting to setup a centralized home-directory server through sshfs and pam-mount.

Currently I am stuck at this point:

When attempting to mount the remote home directory sshfs just gets stuck:

```
d_inevitable@laptop:~$ sshfs -o nonempty,debug server: .
FUSE library version: 2.9.0
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
```

It freezes at this point.

This seems to be because the home directory includes `~/.ssh`. So when I try `sshfs -o nonempty server:.ssh .ssh` the same thing happens.

I suppose fuse somehow initializes the mount, but then ssh needs something from it's config directory so it tries to read from it. Fuse will just block that read resulting in a deadlock.

What kind of stuff does sshfs need from `~/.ssh`?

I have tried to remove all read/write permissions from `~/.ssh` and then mounting on some other directory. That worked fine. The debug output only complained about writing to `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Using sshfs sounds like a bad idea offhand. Why aren't you using NFS??

Comment: @chriss for security reasons. It would be very difficult to satisfy the same requirements with NFS.

Comment: @chriss actually the main reason is this: http://serverfault.com/questions/200759/exportfs-warning-home-user-share-does-not-support-nfs-export

Comment: Oh, that's a strange limitation, I guess I'm used to -nix systems that make sense.

Comment: @chriss I suppose I could convert ecryptfs to a truecrypt volume and then krb5p NFS should work, but that would be a very long and bumpy road (resize partitions, transfer data, key management, etc).

Answer (score 4):

You are right, fuse initiates the mount first, then initiates the ssh process. This causes a problem for you, since by default ssh reads `~/.ssh/ssh_config`, `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

---

, `~/.ssh/id_*` files from user home. This behavior can be changed:

1. `~/.ssh/ssh_config` is the default per-user configuration file. An alternative per-user configuration file can be specified using `-F` option, or use `-F /dev/null` to specify no per-user configuration file.
2. `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is used to store and check host keys. You can use `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`, and either manually add the host key to `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` or use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.
3. `~/.ssh/id_*` files are identity files by default used for client authentication. If you want to authenticate using an identity file, you need to keep it outside the home directory and use `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=<path to private key>`. Or else you can authenticate interactively if you use `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/dev/null -o PubkeyAuthentication=no`.

For example to mount home using sshfs, authenticating using password, without host key checking, run

```
sshfs user@server: ~/ -o nonempty -F /dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/dev/null -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

Comment: Per the OP, the user wants to combine this with pam_mount. This can be done by following your instructions, and adding the above to `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` like so:
`
<fusemount>mount.fuse %(VOLUME) %(MNTPT) -F /dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/dev/null -o %(OPTIONS)</fusemount>

<volume fstype="fuse" path="sshfs#%(USER)@localhost:/home/%(USER)" mountpoint="~" ssh="1" options="reconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,nonempty" />
`